# Chain too wide for gap between chainring and chainring guard

Tags: chain, chainring

I have a [Seek 0 2013](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-au/bikes/model/seek.0/12043/57454/) and recently the chain has been stretched so far that it needed to be replaced. On the Giant site it says that this is sold with a [KMC Z51](http://kmcchain.us/chain/z51/) 1/2" * 3/32" chain.

I've since gone to two different shops who have both sold what appears to be the same sized chain (1/2" * 1/8") which isn't fitting, as it's too wide and brushes against the chainring guard. (This was dumb on my behalf and I have no defense for this.)

Is it possible to still use these chains (perhaps by adjusting / removing the chainring guard) without any complications in the future or are these chains simply the wrong size and I need to go return them and get the right chain?

Comment: Should be fine, but it seems like a bit of a faff to avoid the 10 dollars for a new 3/32" chain.

Comment: On a derailleur-style bike the chain width should match the sprockets, or you will have poor shifting.  On a fixie or internal gear bike, though, correct chain width is not so critical.

Answer (score 2):

> the Giant site it says that this is sold with a KMC Z51 1/2" * 3/32" chain.

So it should have a 3/32" chain.

> I've since gone to two different shops who have both sold what appears to be the same sized chain (1/2" * 1/8")

1/8" = 4/32". That's more than 3/32".

> which isn't fitting, as it's too wide.

Funny that.

1/8" chain isn't stronger unless you spend a lot of money on a high-spec track chain, which would have a more complex construction inside the rollers.

Get a 3/32" chain.

Answer (score 1):

Given the bike operates like a single speed and all the gearing is in the hub, you should be fine removing the chainguard. Be warned though if you cycle in trousers this increases the chance of losing your trouser leg to the bite of chain meeting chainring. You're also more likely to increase the chance of the dreaded chain grease tattoo on legs or trousers.